# Only one select2 dropdown is getting enable = false

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have three select2 dropdown. I am disabling them like this:-

```
$('#rescues').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change')
$('#first_aids').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change')
$('#extinctions').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change')
```

However, only the first one is getting disabled.

[image]

If I don't disable the first one (rescues) but the second one (first_aids), then only the second one is getting disabled, not the third one:-

```
//$('#rescues').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change')
$('#first_aids').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change')
$('#extinctions').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change')
```

[image]

Seems like once one select2 is getting disabled, other's aren't disabled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using line-terminator `;` at the end of statement

Comment: Hi, remove `trigger('change')` this line from all the statements and try again. Working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jLf16ozq/).

Comment: @Swati. Thanks. removing `trigger('change')` did the work. I am doing this separately. `$('#first_aids').val([]).trigger('change');  $('#first_aids').select2('enable', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use line-terminatior `;`

```
$('#rescues').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change');
$('#first_aids').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change');
$('#extinctions').val([]).select2('enable', false).trigger('change');
```

Comment: There's plenty of questions on SO that give links to the exact rules of when a semi-colon is required vs when it's implied.  Personally, I recommend always using `;` as it saves those obscure cases where not using one breaks something.